# Codeowner not able to merge their own Pull requests

Tags: github

- In our git repository we have set some rules for a branch. It needs PR to merge code and needs approval from any one code owner.
- A codeowner is not able to merge his own PRs. He is able to merge other peoples PRs. There is no other setting enabled that will restrict him from merging
- Codeowner file looks like this,

- @codeowner1  @codeowner2 @codeowner3

- The codeowner has write access in the repo
- I thought that he will be able to merge his own PRs since he is a codeowner. But git doesnt even ask review to him for his own PRs.